# Getting the select id value from one select in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

I am trying to check if the options of the select is clicked.

I am trying to get the select id of the `dropdown_replace` class. I cannot use the `edit-field-select-label-und--2` because it is dynamic and it keeps on changing based on the number of options I have.For example if I have two options the select id is `edit-field-select-label-und--2` and if I have 3 options it will be `edit-field-select-label-und--3` So I need to use the div class `dropdown_relpace` to get the select id.

How can I get the select id using jquery?

```
<div id="dropdown-replace">
    <div class="form-item form-type-select form-item-field-select-label-und">
        <label for="edit-field-select-label-und">Label <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
        <select multiple="multiple" name="field_select_label[und][]" id="edit-field-select-label-und--2" class="form-select required">
            <option value="yes">yes</option>
            <option value="no">no</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do...

```
var id = $("#dropdown-replace").find("select").attr("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can also do this:

```
var id = $("#dropdown-replace .form-select").attr("id");
```